# Need help to control LCD screen with Raspberry and Python

Tags: python

I have a LCD successfully connected to a Raspberry and controled with Python code

I'd like to write slowly a word (like typewriting), a letter after a letter

I've tried different possibility but with no success. And I'm stucked. I need help

here is the code to control the writing on the lcd :

```
# Send some centred test
  lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_1, LCD_CMD)
  lcd_string("SENTENCE ONE",2) 
  lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_2, LCD_CMD)
  lcd_string("SENTENCE TWO",2)
  lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_3, LCD_CMD)
  lcd_string("SENTENCE THREE",2)
  lcd_byte(LCD_LINE_4, LCD_CMD)
  lcd_string("SENTENCE FOUR",2)
```

Comment: what is `a` in your code?

Comment: I've deleted the code I've tried because it may cause confusion. I would appreciated that someone could put me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

Not tested , but i guess it should help you get started

```
import time

def typewriter_like(sentence, lcd_line, delay=1):
    for i,letter in enumerate(sentence):
        lcd_byte(lcd_line, LCD_CMD)
        lcd_string(sentence[:i+1], 2)
        time.sleep(delay)


# Use it
typewriter_like("Sentence One", LCD_LINE_1)
```

Comment: If it solves your problem , you can mark the question as answered

Comment: Sorry can't find where to do this !